# mod_proxy_ajp AJP_ attributes are present but not shown from request.getAttributeNames()

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, ajp

AJP_ attributes sent from apache mod_proxy_ajp to tomcat ajp connector can be retrieved with java code like

```
String attributeValue = request.getAttribute(attributeName);
```

Doing so, I have seen that these forwarded attributeNames are not listed in the enumeration we get with **request.getAttributeNames()**.  This last method return only these 4 ones, missing the AJP_* attributes:

```
javax.servlet.forward.request_uri
javax.servlet.forward.context_path
javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path
javax.servlet.forward.path_info
javax.servlet.forward.mapping
```

For example I can retrieve a "groupID" in my java  with request.getAttribute("groupID") but request.getAttributeNames() doesn't list "groupID".   Why ??

ENV: Apache Tomcat/8.5.54 (Debian) Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)

Bernard

Comment: @ebourg can you help?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. These attributes are "hidden" and will not appear in the return value from `ServletRequest.getAttrbuteNames`. You have to know the names of the attributes in order to fetch them.

Comment: This does seem to be the case, I'm not sure about the 'by design' bit though. My top tip to find these attributes is to set allowedRequestAttributesPattern to something that won't match the attribute names, the request will fail stating the names of the incoming attributes that it is taking umbrage at

Comment: Oh, so it's not a bug? And what can be the objective of this "functionality"? The purpose of getAttributeNames is quite clear (give me the names). Hide, without possibility of configuration, seems ugly, and the Servlets specification doesn't seem to encourage this.

Comment: @ggrandes You are welcome to raise that issue with the Tomcat developers on the community user or development mailing list(s). But this is *not* a bug.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz: thank you; I see you very convinced, could you tell me then what is the goal of this functionality/design?

Comment: @ggrandes Do you mean "why is it this way"? I don't know; that decision was made in the distant past and the behavior lives-on today. I *did* suggest that you could directly ask the Tomcat community to get an answer.